# same css but different view in mozila and chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I have same css property but it looks different in chrome and mozila.
i want all those images to float left and with equal margin between them.
but the width of parent div of these images is 100%. and width of the images are also different. i want them to cover the complete area horizontally.

I don't know why it looks different in these browsers.

**HTML**

```
<div class="bottomLogoWrapper">
<h3>Lor separat existentie</h3>
    <div class="logoContainer clearFix">
    <div class="bottomLogo lfloat"><a><img src="images/fireFax.png"></a></div>
    <div class="bottomLogo lfloat"><a><img src="images/optus.png"></a></div>
    <div class="bottomLogo lfloat"><a><img src="images/toyota.png"></a></div>
    <div class="bottomLogo lfloat"><a><img src="images/theIconic.png"></a></div>
    <div class="bottomLogo lfloat"><a><img src="images/kogan.png"></a></div>                    
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.bottomContent > .bottomLogoWrapper{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 50px 15px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #e5e5e5;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.bottomContent > .bottomLogoWrapper h3{
    margin:0 auto 50px;
    color: #3f3f40;
}

.bottomContent .logoContainer{
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.bottomContent .logoContainer .bottomLogo{
    margin: 0 5%;
}

.bottomContent .logoContainer .bottomLogo:last-child{
    margin: 0px;
}

.bottomContent .logoContainer .bottomLogo a{
    cursor: pointer;
}
.bottomContent .logoContainer .bottomLogo img{
    width: 70%

}
```

**Chrome**

[image]

**Mozila**

[image]

Comment: Are you zoomed in? try `CTRL+(mouse wheel backwards)`

Comment: no. its 100% zoom

Comment: please help me to resolve this issue. :(

Comment: You currently do not have enough code for us to reproduce the problem, add more code to your question or give me the link to your site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can add vendor prefixes(webkit,-mos- etc) for the respective browsers in which you want to run your code